# How to prevent uglify in Umijs in build?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, umijs

I'm using [UmiJs](https://umijs.org/) framework , In its build script it uglify all the files , how can I prevent it from uglify them ?

Answer (score 1):

add ! prevent UmiJs from uglify

`'!js/UmiJs.js` '

Comment: where I should write it ?

Comment: @URL87 which library you are using for uglifaty?

Comment: probably the default one here - https://umijs.org/config/#minimizer

Answer (score 1):

Set the environment variable:

```
COMPRESS=none
```

The [docs](https://umijs.org/guide/env-variables.html#compress) mention this var but don't specifically mention uglify/minify and the detail of what's involved. Here's the [source code](https://github.com/umijs/umi/blob/9f2aaf023208969e88c43f8b7ed9739687ab3ed8/packages/af-webpack/src/getWebpackConfig/prod.js#L58) where it's used.